# Adding jackson-core-asl to maven dependencies causes ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, json, maven, spring-mvc, jackson

Part of the project I've been working on requires serializing objects to JSON and passing them to the user. We will be using the Jackson library to do this. Previously I was using version 2.2.3, which was simple enough, but my manager wants to switch back to version 1.9.12. Shouldn't be a problem, 1.9.12 supports everything that we need, but just adding the dependency to the project causes it to basically implode.

The dependency we add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

The project builds just fine. However, running the server causes it to throw this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException
```

followed by about a page of information which I can provide if needed. Trying to load up a web page (which was working previously) causes it to generate a 5MB log file full of errors, and while the page itself loads some of the page entities come out wrong.

A quick check of the compiled .war file shows that the jackson-mapper-asl.jar doesn't contain JsonGenerationException.class, but jackson-core-asl.jar (which I believe is added as part of the jackson-mapper-asl dependency, as it is not listed in the dependencies) does.

I have commented out all of the code relying on Jackson, so the libraries are not used in any way in my code. My suspicion is that Spring is trying to create a JSON mapper for one of the servlets and is somehow crashing. However, I'm not sure why it can't find the dependency.

Comment: Have you done a mvm:dependency tree to check if another library is pulling in jackson as a transitive dependency?

Comment: It appears to only be pulled in at that single place. The webapp pulls in jackson-mapper-asl which pulls in jackson-core-asl.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should  migrate towards "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" Jackson.

see packages on Maven cetral:
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|com.fasterxml.jackson.core

It looks like Jackson project changed base package. I have Spring Boot (1.1.8) project in my workspace and it's using Jackson with this new base package.